# Histogram and qqplot next to each other with par - does not show in PDF

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I have this paired sample which I bound with

```
paired <- cbind(c(before, after))
```

Then I constructed a histogram and a Q-Q plot with

```
hist(paired, freq=FALSE, ylim=range(0,0.7,by=0.2))
curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(paired), sd=sd(paired)), add=TRUE)
qqnorm(paired)
qqline(paired)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
```

If I look at "plots" it is perfectly fine and it shows these two perfectly next to each other. However, when I want to compile into PDF, it only gives me the histogram in the PDF? Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Did you set the height and width of the pdf to be large enough for both?

Comment: First, sorry, of course I included my two vectors in the cbind.

Comment: sorry I thought it worked but it didn't. no matter how I try to get the pdf now into my actual pdf, I'm not sure how to include it.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem with your original code**

`par()` plays no effect as you put it after all plots been made. You will obtain two plots on 2 different graphical devices. If you save them into a `.pdf` file, they will appear in the same file, but on two different pages.

**Solution**

```
# You should put `par(mfrow = c(1,2))` **before** plotting;
par(mfrow = c(1,2))  ## split the plotting region in to 1 row 2 columns
hist(paired, freq=FALSE, ylim=range(0,0.7,by=0.2))
curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(paired), sd=sd(paired)), add=TRUE)
qqnorm(paired)
qqline(paired)
```

Plus: you can use `pdf()` to directly plot on a `.pdf` file. See `?pdf`. But remember to use `def.off()` to close this file before opening it.

```
pdf("test.pdf", height = 6, width = 6)   ## open a graphical device, in this case, a .pdf file
## code above for producing plot
dev.off()  ## close active graphical device, in this case, you .pdf file
```

The resulting `.pdf` file be in your current working directory. If you don't know where it is, do `getwd()` in R.